# RIA Servcies Filter Out Included Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

Below returns all of the people in a building and all of their computers, and this works.

I want to change this to only include the Computers where Active == 1 and only the ActivityLogs where ActivityTypeId == 5.  But if they don’t have either I still want the person returned.

```
  public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople(int BuildingId)
        {
         return this.ObjectContext.People
                .Include("Computers")
                .Include("ActivityLog")
                .Where(p => p.buildingId == BuildingId && !p.migrated)
                .OrderBy(p => p.name);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible using `Include` syntax. As an alternative, you can select each entity individually like so:

```
var queryWithAllData = this.ObjectContext
                           .People
                           .Select(p => new
                           {
                               Person = p,
                               Computers = p.Computers.Where(c => c.Active == 1),
                               ActivityLogs = p.ActivityLog.Where(a => a.ActivityTypeId == 5)
                           });

// Do what you need with the records now that you have all the data.
```

Comment: How do I get this to come back from RIA Services?

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question, as your original one doesn't really ask that question nor include any details on your setup and what you're trying to accomplish.